# Wordpress backend, can't edit post status

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

A former programmer at the company I'm doing my internship right now disabled the function to edit a post_status with the option in the top-right corner of the screen when editting a post. I've searched for a while now but I'm out of options.

After a while I noticed that when I select another theme (twenty eleven) it works again. So it has to be in the theme folder, but I can't find where.

Is there some kind of command I can't find on google that disables it?

PS: the edit link is still there, just doesnt work. I can get the div with the option dropdown menu to show with the google inspector so it is just hidden.

this is the html it gets:

```
<a href="#post_status" class="edit-post-status hide-if-no-js">Edit</a>
```

EDIT: Okay I found it wasn't something that was turned off, but a jQuery include bug. Someone included a jQuery file with this code:

```
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_scripts');
function admin_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('jquery_ui', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_ui');
}
```

[This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) page tells me it already uses that (almost exact) version of jQuery. So because I recently updated the installation, no need for double scripts. :)

Comment: Must be given `display:none;` css for this link. Try to check in css files of that theme.

Comment: That's what I thought, but those classes are never specified. Also, javascript should make it show up again, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Look in functions.php in the theme. That's probably where they disabled meta boxes and edit options.

Or, look for a mu-plugins folder in wp-content and see if there is a "must use" plugin that disables anything.

Comment: Well, it isn't a plugin because then it would not be changed if I changed theme. But I can't find anything that would disable it besides unknown functions.

Comment: mu-plugins will be enabled with all themes; functions.php files only run for the one theme.